# partial not loaded rails-jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

my new.js.erb is like

```
$("#product1-modal").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'new') %>")
$("#product1-modal").modal("show")
```

_new.html.erb like

```
 <div class="modal-header">
 <h3>New Product</h3>
 </div>
 <%= render "form" %>
```

and my _form.html.erb

```
       <%= form_for @product1, remote: true, html: { class: "form-horizontal", style: "display:inline;" } do |f| %>
<div class="modal-body">
<ul class="errors"></ul>

<div class="control-group">
<%= f.label :name, class:"control-label" %>
<div class="controls">
<%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
<%= f.label :price, class: "control-label" %>
<div class="controls">
<%= f.text_field :price %>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<%= link_to "Cancel", "#", class: "btn", data: {dismiss: "modal"} %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

my partial form doesn't loaded
The response I got is looks fine but page not loaded
can any one help me??

when I click on new button response I got is

```
$("#product1-modal").html("<div class=\"modal-header\">\n    <h3>New Product<\/h3>\n    <\/div>\n        <form accept-charset=\"UTF-8\" action=\"/product1s\" class=\"form-horizontal\" data-remote=\"true\" id=\"new_product1\" method=\"post\" style=\"display:inline;\"><div style=\"margin:0;padding:0;display:inline\"><input name=\"utf8\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"&#x2713;\" /><input name=\"authenticity_token\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"mUNwn0fJoZ4lCbJjy8Ju8V78xp+/mjXoZkoqbh0EeOw=\" /><\/div>\n    <div class=\"modal-body\">\n    <ul class=\"errors\"><\/ul>\n     \n    <div class=\"control-group\">\n    <label class=\"control-label\" for=\"product1_name\">Name<\/label>\n    <div class=\"controls\">\n    <input id=\"product1_name\" name=\"product1[name]\" size=\"30\" type=\"text\" />\n    <\/div>\n    <\/div>\n    <div class=\"control-group\">\n    <label class=\"control-label\" for=\"product1_price\">Price<\/label>\n    <div class=\"controls\">\n    <input id=\"product1_price\" name=\"product1[price]\" size=\"30\" type=\"text\" />\n    <\/div>\n    <\/div>\n    <\/div>\n    <div class=\"modal-footer\">\n    <input class=\"btn btn-primary\" name=\"commit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Create Product1\" />\n    <a href=\"#\" class=\"btn\" data-dismiss=\"modal\">Cancel<\/a>\n    <\/div>\n<\/form>\n")
$("#product1-modal").modal("show")
```

index.html.erb

```
    <div class="container">
<div class="well">
<%= link_to "New Product1", new_product1_path, remote: true, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
</div>
<div class="new-product1"></div>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Price</th>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="product1-index">
<%= render "index" %>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div id="product1-modal" class="modal hide fade"></div>
```

Comment: Share html of your (#product1-modal) div as well.
it shoudl have 'modal' class

`<div class = 'modal fade hide' id = 'product1-modal'>`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are giving wrong id

it should be '#product-modal' instead of '#product1-modal' in your new.js.erb file

```
$("#product-modal").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'new') %>")
$("#product-modal").modal("show")
```

update your new.js.erb file

Answer (score 0):

It might not be this but if there are no semicolons in your new.js.erb, that can cause problems

If there are none, try adding them.

```
$("#product1-modal").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'new') %>");
$("#product1-modal").modal("show");
```